# Sorting a singly linked list with natural merge sort in C

Tags: algorithm, c, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

This C program implements a so-called *natural* merge sort that identifies existing runs in the list and exploits them in order to sort in sub-linearithmic time whenever possible. The running time of this sort is \$\Theta(n \log m)\$, where \$n\$ is the length of the list and \$m\$ is the number of ordered *runs* (ascending or descending sublists). Since \$m\$ is at most \$\lceil n / 2 \rceil\$, this runs in worst-case linearithmic time. Here we go:

**linked_list.h**

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linked_list_node_t {
    int value;
    struct linked_list_node_t* next;
} linked_list_node_t;

typedef struct {
    linked_list_node_t* head;
    linked_list_node_t* tail;
    size_t size;
} linked_list_t;

void linked_list_init(linked_list_t* list);
void linked_list_append(linked_list_t* list, int value);
void linked_list_sort(linked_list_t* list);
int  linked_list_is_sorted(linked_list_t* list);
void linked_list_display(linked_list_t* list);

#endif /* LINKED_LIST_H */
```

**linked_list.c**

```
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void linked_list_init(linked_list_t* list)
{
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
}

void linked_list_append(linked_list_t* list, int value)
{
    linked_list_node_t* node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    node->value = value;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (list->head)
    {
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }

    list->size++;
}

int linked_list_is_sorted(linked_list_t* list)
{
    linked_list_node_t* node1;
    linked_list_node_t* node2;

    if (list->size < 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    node1 = list->head;
    node2 = node1->next;

    while (node2)
    {
        if (node1->value > node2->value)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        node1 = node2;
        node2 = node2->next;
    }

    return 1;
}

void linked_list_display(linked_list_t* list)
{
    char* separator = "";

    for (linked_list_node_t* node = list->head; node; node = node->next)
    {
        printf("%s%d", separator, node->value);
        separator = ", ";
    }
}

static linked_list_node_t* reverse(linked_list_node_t* head)
{
    linked_list_node_t* new_head = head;
    linked_list_node_t* tmp_head;

    tmp_head = head;
    head = head->next;
    tmp_head->next = NULL;

    while (head)
    {
        tmp_head = head;
        head = head->next;
        tmp_head->next = new_head;
        new_head = tmp_head;
    }

    return new_head;
}

static linked_list_node_t* merge(linked_list_node_t* left_list,
                                 linked_list_node_t* right_list)
{
    linked_list_node_t* merged_head = NULL;
    linked_list_node_t* merged_tail = NULL;
    linked_list_node_t* tmp_node;

    if (left_list->value < right_list->value)
    {
        merged_head = left_list;
        merged_tail = left_list;
        left_list = left_list->next;
    }
    else
    {
        merged_head = right_list;
        merged_tail = right_list;
        right_list = right_list->next;
    }

    while (left_list && right_list)
    {
        if (left_list->value < right_list->value)
        {
            tmp_node = left_list;
            left_list = left_list->next;
            merged_tail->next = tmp_node;
            merged_tail = tmp_node;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp_node = right_list;
            right_list = right_list->next;
            merged_tail->next = tmp_node;
            merged_tail = tmp_node;
        }
    }

    // Add the rest to the merged list:
    if (left_list)
    {
        merged_tail->next = left_list;
    }
    else
    {
        merged_tail->next = right_list;
    }

    return merged_head;
}

typedef struct {
    linked_list_node_t** run_length_array;
    size_t head_index;
    size_t tail_index;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} run_list_t;


static void run_list_enqueue(run_list_t* run_list, linked_list_node_t* run_head)
{
    run_list->run_length_array[run_list->tail_index] = run_head;
    run_list->tail_index = (run_list->tail_index + 1) % run_list->capacity;
    run_list->size++;
}

static linked_list_node_t*
scan_ascending_run(run_list_t* run_list,
                   linked_list_node_t* run_start_node)
{
    linked_list_node_t* node1 = run_start_node;
    linked_list_node_t* probe;
    linked_list_node_t* before_probe = NULL;

    int last_read_integer = run_start_node->value;

    probe = node1->next;

    while (probe && last_read_integer <= probe->value)
    {
        last_read_integer = probe->value;
        before_probe = probe;
        probe = probe->next;
    }

    if (probe)
    {
        if (before_probe)
        {
            before_probe->next = NULL;
        }
    }

    run_list_enqueue(run_list, run_start_node);
    return probe;
}

static linked_list_node_t*
scan_descending_run(run_list_t* run_list,
                    linked_list_node_t* run_start_node)
{
    linked_list_node_t* node1 = run_start_node;
    linked_list_node_t* probe;
    linked_list_node_t* before_probe = NULL;

    int last_read_integer = run_start_node->value;

    probe = node1->next;

    while (probe && last_read_integer >= probe->value)
    {
        last_read_integer = probe->value;
        before_probe = probe;
        probe = probe->next;
    }

    if (probe)
    {
        if (before_probe)
        {
            before_probe->next = NULL;
        }
    }

    run_start_node = reverse(run_start_node);
    run_list_enqueue(run_list, run_start_node);
    return probe;
}

static void run_list_build(run_list_t* run_list, linked_list_t* list)
{
    linked_list_node_t* node1;
    linked_list_node_t* node2;
    linked_list_node_t* tmp_node;

    run_list->capacity = list->size / 2 + 1;
    run_list->size = 0;
    run_list->run_length_array =
        malloc(run_list->capacity * sizeof(linked_list_node_t*));

    run_list->head_index = 0;
    run_list->tail_index = 0;

    node1 = list->head;
    node2 = node1->next;

    while (node1)
    {
        node2 = node1->next;

        if (!node2)
        {
            run_list_enqueue(run_list, node1);
            return;
        }

        // Get run direction (ascending 1,2,3... or descending 3,2,1):
        if (node1->value <= node2->value)
        {
            node1 = scan_ascending_run(run_list, node1);
        }
        else
        {
            node1 = scan_descending_run(run_list, node1);
        }
    }
}

static linked_list_node_t* run_list_dequeue(run_list_t* run_list)
{
    linked_list_node_t* ret = run_list->run_length_array[run_list->head_index];
    run_list->head_index = (run_list->head_index + 1) % run_list->capacity;
    run_list->size--;
    return ret;
}

static size_t run_list_size(run_list_t* run_list)
{
    return run_list->size;
}

void linked_list_sort(linked_list_t* list)
{
    run_list_t run_list;
    linked_list_node_t* left_run;
    linked_list_node_t* right_run;
    linked_list_node_t* merged_run;

    if (!list || list->size < 2)
    {
        // Trivially sorted or non-existent list once here.
        return;
    }

    run_list_build(&run_list, list);

    while (run_list_size(&run_list) != 1)
    {
        left_run = run_list_dequeue(&run_list);
        right_run = run_list_dequeue(&run_list);
        merged_run = merge(left_run, right_run);
        run_list_enqueue(&run_list, merged_run);
    }

    list->head = run_list_dequeue(&run_list);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void load_linked_list(linked_list_t* list, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    int value;

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        value = rand();
        linked_list_append(list, value);
    }
}

void load_presorted_list(linked_list_t* list, size_t len)
{
    int i;
    size_t chunk_length = len / 4;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        linked_list_append(list, i % chunk_length);
    }
}

static size_t milliseconds()
{
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    return t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    size_t ta;
    size_t tb;

    linked_list_t list;
    linked_list_t large_list;
    linked_list_t large_presorted_list;

    linked_list_init(&list);
    linked_list_init(&large_list);
    linked_list_init(&large_presorted_list);

    linked_list_append(&list, 5);
    linked_list_append(&list, 1);
    linked_list_append(&list, 2);
    linked_list_append(&list, 9);
    linked_list_append(&list, 6);
    linked_list_append(&list, 7);
    linked_list_append(&list, 10);
    linked_list_append(&list, 8);
    linked_list_append(&list, 4);
    linked_list_append(&list, 3);    
    // Small demo:
    linked_list_display(&list);
    puts("");

    linked_list_sort(&list);
    linked_list_display(&list);
    puts("");

    // Large benchmark:
    load_linked_list(&large_list, 1000 * 1000);

    ta = milliseconds();
    linked_list_sort(&large_list);
    tb = milliseconds();

    printf("Sorted large array in %zu milliseconds. Sorted: %d\n",
           tb - ta,
           linked_list_is_sorted(&large_list));

    // Large presorted benchmark:
    load_presorted_list(&large_presorted_list, 1000 * 1000);

    ta = milliseconds();
    linked_list_sort(&large_presorted_list);
    tb = milliseconds();

    printf("Sorted large presorted array in %zu milliseconds. Sorted: %d\n",
           tb - ta,
           linked_list_is_sorted(&large_presorted_list));

    return 0;
}
```

## Critique request

Please tell me how can I improve my C programming routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` can fail. Deal with it.

If you don't modify something passed by pointer, mark it `const`. Const-correctness, if rigorously followed, is a great help for debugging and understanding, and a right pain otherwise.

Consider taking advantage of the possibility to intersperse variable-declarations in code since C99. It's succh a nice feature even ancient C90 compilers allow it as an extension.
This way you can declare and initialize variables where you need them, keeping their scopes minimal and easier to review.

There is nobody stopping you from modifying function-arguments. Might eliminate some variables that way...

`int`s are easily copied. And sentinels allow for the elimination of special-cases, the bane of elegance and efficiency.

```
int linked_list_is_sorted(const linked_list_t* list) {
    int last = INT_MIN;
    for(linked_list_node_t* node = list->head; node; node = node->next) {
        if(node->value < last)
            return 0;
        last = node->value;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Consider `const`-qualifying all pointers to string-literals. While in C the type is still `char[N]`, it is immutable.

How about changing the format-string instead of an insert?

```
void linked_list_display(const linked_list_t* list) {
    const char* format = "%d";
    for(linked_list_node_t* node = list->head; node; node = node->next) {
        printf(format, node->value);
        format = ", %d";
    }
}
```

The conditional operator (`exp ? true_val : false_val`) is superb for choosing between two expressions.

Double-pointers are not scary. And using them allows you to avoid needless duplication.

```
static linked_list_node_t* merge(linked_list_node_t* a, linked_list_node_t* b) {
    linked_list_node_t* head = NULL;
    linked_list_node_t** insert = &head;

    while (a && b) {
        linked_list_node_t** chosen = b->value < a->value ? &b : &a;
        *insert = *chosen;
        *chosen= (*chosen)->next;
        insert = &(*insert)->next
    }

    *insert = a ? a : b;
    return head;
}
```

Integral remainder is a somewhat costly operation. And as you know that `0 <= n < 2 * m` in `n % m`, you can replace it with a cheaper conditional subtraction.

`return 0;` is implicit for `main()` since C99. Might be interesting...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was aiming to full ANSI C support with `pedantic` `ansi` `Wall`.